# What JVM is doing internally when it encounters an assert statement in java program?

Tags: java, assert, assertion

I am new to the assertions concept in java.
Where ever i read about the *assert* concept in java, it is always saying like, if we use *assert expression1:expression2*, it will use the default constructor or one of the seven constructors in AssertionError class in case it fails. 
**But what my doubt is Who is actually throwing this *AssertionError* error when the assert statement fails ?** Will the compiler adds the "***throw new AssertionError(---)***" or the JVM will check for the expression and throw the *AssertionError* (like *ArithmeticException*, *NullPointerException* etc...) ?

Comment: Hi Jarrod, My question is who is exactly taking care of assert statement. Whether the Compiler or the JVM. But the above example is saying how to use the assert statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [assertion proposal](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/asrt_prop.html) explains it:

> The assert statement [is] merely syntactic sugar for this if
>   statement:
>
> ```
> if ($assertionsEnabled && !(Expression1))
>     throw new AssertionError(Expression2);
> ```

`$assertionsEnabled` is a synthetic boolean field that also gets added by the compiler.

Comment: Which means the JVM doesn't actually do anything special; it's a compiler feature.

Comment: Thanks Kapep and David

Comment: @DavidEhrmann actually not only compiler feature: the value of `$assertionsEnabled` is initialized for every class based on JVM options like -ea, -esa, so the class asks `Class.desiredAssertionStatus()` which communicates to VM to get this status.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kapep and David for your quick response.

Finally I got the practical proof :)

**Foo.java**

```
package pack1;
public class Foo {
    public void m1( int value ) {
        assert 0 <= value;
        System.out.println( "OK" );
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.print( "foo.m1(  1 ): " );
        foo.m1( 1 );
        System.out.print( "foo.m1( -1 ): " );
        foo.m1( -1 );
    }
}
```

And when I try with javap command finally I can see the following output with assertion related information added by compiler.

C:>javap pack1.Foo

Compiled from "Foo.java"

```
public class pack1.Foo {
  static final boolean $assertionsDisabled;
  public pack1.Foo();
  public void m1(int);
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  static {};
}
```